# Splitting function arguments by a null?

Tags: javascript

Say my function is called as,

```
my_function(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3);
```

and I want to split it into separate segments that last up until a null.

Here's what I have so far:

```
my_function = (...theArgs) => {
    let _theArgs = [];
    let _tempArray = [];
    let j = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < theArgs.length; i++) {
        if (theArgs[i] != null) {
            _tempArray[j].push(theArgs[i]); //breaks here
        } else {
            _theArgs[j].push(_tempArray); //and here
            _tempArray = [];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return _theArgs;
}

my_function(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3);
```

So here I am trying to cycle through each argument passed to the function and split it up into a 2D array. For instance, `my_function(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3);` would return an array `_theArgs` where `_theArgs[0] = [1, 2, 5]`, `_theArgs[1] = [4]` and `_theArgs[2] = [1, 3]`

I've indicated where my code breaks.. any suggestion to approaching this would be much appreciated

Comment: `_tempArray[j]` and `_theArgs[j]` are not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_tempArray[j].push()` fails because `_tempArray[j]` is not an array. `_tempArray` is initially an empty array, there's nothing in `_tempArray[j]`, so you can't push onto it. I think you just want `_tempArray.push(theArgs[i])`.

The same with `_theArgs[j]`.

You also need to push onto `_theArgs` at the end of the function, to get arguments after the last `null`.

```js
my_function = (...theArgs) => {
    let _theArgs = [];
    let _tempArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < theArgs.length; i++) {
        if (theArgs[i] !== null) {
            _tempArray.push(theArgs[i]);
        } else {
            _theArgs.push(_tempArray);
            _tempArray = [];
        }
    }
    if (_tempArray.length > 0) {
        _theArgs.push(_tempArray);
    }
    return _theArgs;
}

console.log(my_function(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3));
```

Comment: Seems like maybe it shouldn't add an empty array if there are two nulls in a row (but that's not specified in the OP).

Comment: @MarkMeyer It will also add an empty array if the first arg is `null`. If either of these are issues, just add `if (_tempArray.length > 0)` around `_theArgs.push(_tempArray)`, just like I do at the end.

Comment: Probably want to use `===` since `undefined == null`

Comment: I doubt that matters in any practical use.

Comment: It's just that the question specifically asked for a null

Comment: Just because that's what they said it doesn't mean it's what they really mean. But I made the change, since it obviously can't matter if `undefined` never actually appears.

Answer (score 3):

You could search for `null` and push the parts to the result array.

```js
function fn(...args) {
    var result = [],
        r = 0,
        l;
    while ((l = args.indexOf(null, l)) !== -1) {
        result.push(args.slice(r, l));
        r = l + 1;
        l += 2;
    }
    result.push(args.slice(r));
    return result;
}

console.log(fn(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3));
```

Comment: Nice one :) FWIW, this adds an empty array at the end if the last argument `null`. Technically correct, but may not be what the OP wants. I didn't check the other answers, they may suffer from the same problem.

Comment: if needed, op could add a while loop in advance for adjusting the length of the array, like `while (args[args.length -1] === null) --args.length;`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call `push()` on an undefined nested array object (that is being accessed via the `j` variable).

Consider making the following changes:

```js
const my_function = (...theArgs) => {
    
    let _theArgs = [];
    let _tempArray = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < theArgs.length; i++) {
        if (theArgs[i] != null) {

            // Push to _tempArray directly. No need to access via "j"
            _tempArray.push(theArgs[i]);
        } else {

            // Push to _theArgs directly. No need to access via "j"
            _theArgs.push(_tempArray);
            _tempArray = [];
        }
    }
    
    // Include last args items (if any after final null)
    if(_tempArray.length > 0) {
       _theArgs.push(_tempArray);
    }
    
    return _theArgs;
}

const result = my_function(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why should he try this? A good answer should explain what's wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Been a long night. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the feedback, have updated the answer :-)

Comment: @MikeK hope this helps (I know the feeling :-) )

Comment: @ggorlen ah, thanks for spotting this - just updated answer - appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

The `j` index is throwing you off; remove it in both cases (it's an `undefined` offset; `push` will create the new element automatically).

Also, you'll need to append the final `_tempArray` before returning the result to ensure the last row is added.

Here's a cleaner version which avoids indexes entirely:

```js
const myFunction = (...args) => {
  let row = [];
  
  const result = args.reduce((a, e) => {
    if (e === null) {
      a.push(row);
      row = [];
    } 
    else {
      row.push(e);
    }

    return a;
  }, []);
  
  return row.length ? result.concat([row]) : result;
}

console.log(myFunction(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3));
```

Comment: Should it really add an empty array if the last arg is null of if there are more than one null in a row?

Comment: Unspecified, but fixing that as you wrote this!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: (Since you are pushing you don't need the variable `j`)

```js
my_function = (...theArgs) => {
    let _theArgs = [];
    let _tempArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < theArgs.length; i++) {
        if (theArgs[i] != null) {
            _tempArray.push(theArgs[i]); //breaks here
        } else {
            _theArgs.push(_tempArray); //and here
            _tempArray = [];
        }
    }
    return _theArgs;
}

console.log(my_function(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3));
```

Comment: This is the same as the previous 2 answers.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, by the time I finished up writing you two already posted.

Answer (score 0):

Short and Sweet - not recommended for server-side scripts because its not as performant as a for loop solution but for the client you may save some bandwidth. Also note that this solution, as presented, only works with numbers, nulls and modern browsers.

```js
my_function = (...theArgs) => {
  var _theArgs = theArgs.toString().split(',,');

  for(arg in _theArgs) {
    _theArgs[arg] = _theArgs[arg].split(',').map(function(v) {return +v })
  }
  return _theArgs;
};

console.log(my_function(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3) );
```

Comment: The resulting output has little to do with OP's expected output.

Comment: You should mention that this solution only works for numbers.

Comment: In my haste I did publish a solution that output arrays of strings but it has been revised. I wanted to offer a solution no one else was proposing to spark some learning and abstract thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

```
function my_function(...args) {
    var i = 0, temp = [], lastElt = null;
    for (j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
        if (args[j] !== null) {
            if (temp[i] === undefined) {
                temp[i] = [];
            }
            temp[i].push(args[j]);
        } else if (lastElt !== null) {
            i++;
        }
        lastElt = args[j];
    }
    return temp;
}

var test = my_function(null, 1, 2, 5, null, null, 4, null, null, null, 1, 3);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

As covered in earlier answers the problem is caused by processing a second dimension of `_theArgs` and `_tempArray` when only one (or the first) dimension should be used.

Removing two occurences of `[j]` and the `j++;` line will fix this but needs patch-up code to include an array of arguments that follow the last `null` argument.

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` to avoid explicit loop code  and patchups as may be required:

```js
const args2D = (...argList) =>
    argList.reduce(
        (result, arg) => {
            if (arg === null){
                result.push( [] );
            }
            else {
               result[ result.length-1].push( arg);
            }
            return result;
        },
        [[]]
     );

console.log( args2D(1, 2, 5, null, 4, null, 1, 3));
```

This approach always produces a two dimensional array, with empty inner array(s) if the argument list is empty, or no non-null values follow a `null` value in the list.